# How to bring only rows in which a field repeats itself but another field varies within a range?

Tags: mysql

I have a table called services, with a field "id_client" and a field "id_product".

I need a query that returns all clients that have used all products in a certain list, for example, all clients that have used products 151, 461 and 2047. How would I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could count the number of unique products they have within that list, and make sure they have them all:

```
SELECT   id_client
FROM     services
WHERE    id_product IN (151, 461, 2047)
GROUP BY id_client
HAVING   COUNT(DISTINCT id_product) = 3
```